# passing a list of Types generically for use in a generic method

Tags: c#, generics, .net-3.5, compact-framework

Given the list of types:

```
public class TypeLists
{
    public static List<Type> types 
    {
        get
        {
            return new List<Type>() { typeof(ValueBool), typeof(ValueInt), typeof(ValueDouble), typeof(ValueString) };
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to pass this or other lists in order to use them generically in a method which would cast an accompanying object parameter in the following manner:

```
public static SettingValueUnit UsingAType<T>(object value)
{
    var a = (T)value;
}
```

I attempt to implement its use:

```
foreach (Type t in TypeLists.types)
{
    SettingValueUnit ValueUnit = UsingAType<t>(D.SettingValue.value);
}
```

But I get the following error

Error   1   't' is inaccessible due to its protection level

I am constrained to .Net 3.5 compact framework. 
I would appreciate any help.

Comment: I now realize the nature of this error was odd because I was working in a sandboxed version of the compact framework.

Answer (score 2):

I'm surprised at the *nature* of the error method you're getting, but not the fact that you're getting an error in the first place.

You can't specify a generic argument as an expression - the aim is for it to be a *compile-time* specification of types. If you really want to do this, you'll need to use reflection:

```
// The ... is because we don't know the name of the type containing the method
Method method = typeof(...).GetMethod("UsingAType").MakeGenericMethod(t);
method.Invoke(...);
```